# Magento 2 API usage internally

Tags: magento2, api

i am doing several custom modules in Magento 2.

It is a good practice do all the thing orientated to API (thinking in be consume for an mobile app for example ) and also use those api internally in the view model?

Or should i create a controller for return json to the view model and API just for external calls?

For example, i want to show a popup with a list of products using KOjs.

should i use a controller to return the products of that AJAX call o can i use the magento 2 API "rest/V1/products"

Answer (score 1):

Better to go with webapi.xml and create REST end point approach.

Because you can easily adapt the Magento customer/admin inbuilt token-based restrictions against the APIs.

Comment: webapi.xml and REST are the correct way to go. When in doubt, take a look at the Magento native checkout, they do exactly that